# Consulta MySQL recursiva

Tags: mysql, sql, ordenamiento

Buenas tardes colegas, espero puedan ayudarme con esta consulta que me vuelve loco.
Verán tengo una tabla con datos como estos

[image: Imagen ilustrativa]

Y necesito una consulta SQL me orden los datos de esta forma

- Vertebrados
- Mono
- Gato
- Perro
- Caballo
- Mula
- Invertebrados
- Serpiente
- Saltamontes
- Mosca
- Estrellita de mar

¿Como podría formular la consulta? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta consulta obtiene lo que buscas:

```
 SELECT distinct t2.descripcion AS DESCRIPCION 
  FROM Animalitos as t1 
LEFT JOIN Animalitos AS t2 ON (t2.id_referencia = t1.id OR t1.id = t2.id ) 
ORDER BY t1.id_referencia ASC, t1.id ASC, t2.id ASC, t2.id_referencia ASC
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Muchas gracias!!** exactamente lo que buscaba y me dio el resultado que necesitaba!!! :) Aunque si no es mucha molestía, podrías explicarme como se comporta esta consulta? me confundo un poco. con inner join a ella misma

Comment: @ArielChepito Y tendrás que seguir haciendo `JOIN` con ella misma por cada categoría que agregues. Si son 100 categorías: 100 JOIN y 100 ORDER BY, y si son 200: 200 JOIN y 200 ORDER BY... En los modelos de datos hay que usar el sentido común: **un vertebrado es un tipo de animal, no un animal en sí** :) por eso no debe estar en esa tabla, sino en otra.

Comment: Es muy cierto lo que menciona A. Cedano, esta consulta sólo aplica cuando tiene dos niveles: Categoría/Animal. Pero si tienes, por ejemplo Vertebrado/Bipedo/ave/canario, es decir, hay mas niveles, tendrías que agregar N JOINS, de ese modo, esta SQL no serviría. MySQL maneja la relaciones recursivas como una lista plana padre-hijo, a diferencia de ORACLE que lo maneja bastante bien.

Comment: Gracias por la observación y por el comentario de las bases de datos, afortunadamente la tabla en la que necesito aplicarlo solamente es dos niveles. Muchas gracias a ambos por tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ordenarla así, agregar una nueva columna '**es_vertebrado**' (*por ejemplo*) de tipo int, en donde **1**, indica que es vertebrado, y **0** que es invertebrado.
La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT * FROM animalito ORDER BY es_vertebrado DESC, ID ASC
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero mi problema es que se pueden agregar "categorias" de forma indefinida, es decir, en vez de vertebrado  o invertebrado podría agregar reptiles, mamiferos, aves, anfibios, peces y cada uno con sus "hijos". Como hacer un menu de solo un nivel

Comment: En ese caso **necesitas otra tabla** llamada por ejemplo `categoria_animales`, piensa en la vida real: vertebrados no debería estar en tu tabla `animales` , pues no es un animal, sino una categoría de animal. Lo mismo invertebrado, insecto, reptil... Puedes agregar una relación entre ambas tablas y ningún problema. Si te decides por esa opción te puedo mostrar un ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia A. Cedano. Así lo haría pero  **tengo** que hacerlo de esta manera.

Answer (score -2):

Creo que debes de ver este video:

https://youtu.be/vtg5VaJaqXc

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad lee [answer]

Comment: Este es genial!

Comment: https://youtu.be/7GpyHedM4pw